# How to create php pagination based on amount of MySQL results in an iframe without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination, datatables

I am trying to create some pagination and I'm not sure the best way to go about it. Currently the query is being run in a class file and then the results are printed out in an iframe. The pagination is to be based on the number of results, which is currently over 10 thousand, so the results take a few seconds to load in the iframe. It's currently using the JQuery datatables plug-in. I know datatables has pagination, but someone, at some point disabled it, and for all intents and purposes, I can't use it. So I need to come up with an alternative.

I thought I was smart by running a count on the results, and then storing that count in a session variable and then base the pagination on that, limiting it to 999 results per page, but since the storing of the variable and the query running happens at the same time, the page needs to reload for any pagination to show up and I don't want to have to reload the query. (Sorry for the run-on/long sentence there)

Short version: I need a way to asynchronously run the query, get the count, and have the pagination show up at the same time, and I just don't know how to go about it. I'm not super familiar with the ins and outs of JQuery and AJAX, but is that where my solution lies? I can show code if I need to, but I need more guidance than syntactic help.

Thanks

Comment: How familiar are you with PHP and SQL query strings?

Comment: Very familiar, what's your recommendation?

Comment: lets see the code you have so far, fiddle would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a json with the "count" of registers, after that you can divide the result by the amount of register per page, for instance you have 20 registers in table 'contacts' and you want to see 5 per page, you can divide 20/5, it gave you like result 4, this will be the amount of pages; then you will use 'limit' and 'offset' in sql defining how many registers do you want with limit and from where the search should start with offset.

Comment: I actually already did the math, it's just not showing up when I want it to, but it's good to see that my calculation thought process was correct! I didn't think to use JSON, and frankly, I've never really used it. I'll give it a shot and see what I can come up with. Thanks!

Comment: youre welcome! if you use cakephp, it has 'paginator' method to do automatically the paginate, if you use other framework it should have too!!

Answer (score 0):

So, I haven't run this to check syntax, but it should be good. This one query when used in PHP in conjunction with your AJAX call this should return everything you need as well as handle the pagination, this will also return the number of pages when using the defined results per page variable.

```
$resultsPerPage = (isset($_GET['resultsPerPage'] ? $_GET['resultsPerPage'] : 20);
$currentPage = (isset($_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : 1);
$sql = "SELECT *, (COUNT(ID)/". $resultsPerPage .") AS pages FROM table OFFSET ". (($currentPage - 1) * $resultsPerPage) ." LIMIT ". $resultsPerPage;
```

I think this is what you were looking for? all that's left other than this is formatting and implementation.

Note actual SQL commands omitted because I don't know what engine or method you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The datatables pagination is not something that should be disabled in this case, you should reenable it, and focus on whats really the issue: you have 10,000 rows, you should look at implementing a server side solution of datatables rather than client side, it says specifically that 10,000 is the magic number to make it viable

Comment: I tried to enable it, and according to datatable files, it is set to be enabled. I'm assuming someone else working on the code prior to me disabled it some other way. I decided to not use datatables at all and just run the whole thing server-side. Thanks.

Comment: I would, but datatables has a lot of subfolders, and I honestly don't even know where or how the pagination functionality is being shut off. I've decided to make my own form of datatables, which is working fine.

Comment: glad youre working out, but datatables (javascript) should only be one file include, unless you are using editor, are we talking about the same thing here?